# Multiple quantities with options

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, dropdown

I have a medical lens website and I tried to make custom order product in woocommerce. I want 2 options. When the first one is chosen, it hides 2 dropdown lists and shows only 1 drop down list, and when I choose the second option, it hides 1 dropdown list and shows 2 dropdown lists and each one has the count of quantities.

Example:

[image: Different number of drop down lists based on options]

How can I do this?

I tried to make this with Variable Product but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

this is not currently possible with a product variation as you have found but bundle and composite products do have the ability to add variables inside

https://woocommerce.com/products/product-bundles/

pick and mix bundles may be your answer